# React Native set the current slide to state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am using Swiper (which is using ScrollView) in my react native app. First I need to go through a list of JSON object to render each of slides using map. my problem is I am not sure how to set the current slide info to the state. Just to mention I am using redux.

Probably this should be achieved when the scroll ends using onMomentumScrollEnd

Here is the code snippet

```
var mySlides = [{id: 1, text: "text 1", sub: "sub 1", image: require("./img/1.jpg")}, {id: 2, text: "text 2", sub: "sub 2", image: require("./img/2.jpg")}, {id: 3, text: "text 3", sub: "sub 3", image: require("./img/3.jpg")}]

export default class extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Swiper style={styles.wrapper}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={(e, state, context) => console.log('index:', state.index)}
          >
          {mySlides.map((slide, index) => {
            return (
              <View key="index" style={styles.slide}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={slide.image}>
                  <View style={styles.backdropView}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{slide.text}</Text>
                  </View>
                </Image>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </Swiper>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looks through the `Swiper` docs, I think you're right in using the `onMomentumScollEnd` to track which slide is currently selected. What you can do is that once this function gets called, you can store the `state.index` (state here being the state of the `Swiper`) to the state of your component. Then use the stored index to reference the slide info.

For example:

```
var mySlides = [{id: 1, text: "text 1", sub: "sub 1", image: require("./img/1.jpg")}, {id: 2, text: "text 2", sub: "sub 2", image: require("./img/2.jpg")}, {id: 3, text: "text 3", sub: "sub 3", image: require("./img/3.jpg")}]

export default class extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      index: 0
    };
  }

  handleOnMomentumScrollEnd(e, state) {
    this.setState({
      index: state.index
    });
  }

  render () {
    // current slide info would be accessed by:
    // const currentSlide = mySlides[this.state.index];
    return (
      <View>
        <Swiper style={styles.wrapper}
          onMomentumScrollEnd={this.handleOnMomentumScrollEnd.bind(this)}
        >
          {mySlides.map((slide, index) => {
            return (
              <View key={index} style={styles.slide}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={slide.image}>
                  <View style={styles.backdropView}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>{slide.text}</Text>
                  </View>
                </Image>
              </View>
            );
          })}
        </Swiper>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Also, as a side note, you want to make the `key` of a component unique so changed `key="index"` to `key={index}`

Comment: Thanks I guess thats the only and best solution for this